# Making a web application from a heavy windows program

Tags: web, cloud

We have a pretty heavy windows c++ application with UI and 3D visualization and would like to expose some of its functionality as a web application. At the moment we are at the phase where we should choose a fitting technology stack. As a prototype we simply created a js-frontend (bootstrap + ThreeJs) <-> web-api (c# AspNetCore) <-> redis (not really necessary, mostly used as IPC) <-> backend (our application) combination, put it all into a windows core virtual machine and let it run in the AWS EC2 cloud. It works as a prototype, but we cannot run a production system like that: deployment and scaling is complicated and requires a lot of proprietary scripting. It is also pretty expensive to scale.

My question is: what would be a "contemporary" approach for such a task. Some points about the application, use cases, etc:

- The basic workflow is: a user uploads a file, gets a visualization of it, configures some parameters  and starts a potentially pretty long operation which can take up to some minutes. The result is also visualized and can be downloaded.
- We were able to "turn off" the application UI so that it can run in the headless server, but it is still about 100Mb large executable after all the cuts we could do in a reasonable time. It is a windows application and cannot be easily converted to linux. We do plan to split it later into some smaller-micro-services and make linux-compatible, but it is definitely not the next task in our list.
- The proposed architecture should be cheap to run and easly scalable (of cause :)).